# Django + DRF + Celery: выполнить celery_task.delay() только после завершения транзакции (реального выполнения model.save())

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, celery, atomic

Я пытался использовать указанный в доках метод on_commit, но всё равно внутри таска получаю ModelDoesNotExistError.

views.py:

```
    class SomeViewset(viewsets.ModelViewset):
        ...
        @action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
        def some_action(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            m = MyModel()
    
            with transaction.atomic():
                m.save()
                transaction.on_commit(lambda:
                                          my_fav_task.delay(m.id, param2, param3))
            return Response({"success": True, "operation_id": m.id}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

tasks.py:

```
@shared_task
def my_fav_task(operation_id, **params):
    print(operation_id)  # We get new id
    print(MyModel.objects.all())  # No newly created object here
    operation = MyModel.objects.get(id=operation_id)  # Error here
```

Comment: А можно тупой вопрос: вы уверены, что Celery работает с той же самой базой данных, что и Django?

Comment: @andreymal Да, есть другие таски, которые добавляют данные в базу. Проблема именно в асинхронности бд и celery